# Global variable invalid syntax with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

:)

I'm playing around with multiprocesing, and Qt. I want to create a variable, which is global, and use this in a function, when I close my window, to kill the background process.

```
import sys, multiprocessing, time

def proc():
    while True:
        print "Runinn'..."  
        time.sleep(1)
    return

def onExit():
    p.terminate()
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit
    return
.
.
.
button.clicked.connect(onExit())
.
.
.
global p=multiprocessing.Process(target=proc())
p.start()
```

The interpreter throws an error,

```
    global p=multiprocessing.Process(target=proc())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like `p` is already in the global namespace.  the `global` statement effectively does nothing here...

Answer (score 5):

`global` only takes the names to put into the global scope for the current function. The assignment must be performed separately.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how you use [`global`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html).

First, the code structure should be like this:

```
global p
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=proc())
p.start()
```

Notice how you declare a name to be global on one line, and then assign it on a different one that is below the global-statement.

Second, you would only do this *inside* a function that *reassigns* `p`.  Doing it on the outside or in a function that doesn't  reassign `p` accomplishes nothing.

Lastly, you need to define `p` *before* you call `onExit`.  Once again, since `onExit` does not reassign `p` and especially since `p` is already global, you do not need to do `global p`.

Comment: It's still not global, but that error disappeared.
The new one:
    p.terminate()
NameError: global name 'p' is not defined

Comment: @erbal - Yea, that is because you are calling `onExit` before you define `p`.  Instead, define `p` first.

Comment: @erbal - Happy to have helped!  Please don't forget to accept either my or Ignacio's answer so that people know that this question is answered.